# Get all MongoDB entries with id comparasion (gt/lt) with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have a MongoDB connection like this:

```
public SessionRepository()
{
    Client = new MongoClient();
    Database = Client.GetDatabase("mnemosyne");
    Collection = Database.GetCollection<SessionModel>("session");
}
```

I can get a list of MongoDB documents like this:

```
public List<SessionModel> Get()
{
    var query = this.Collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
    var sessions = query.Result;;
    return sessions;
}
```

I am trying to get all documents with an `_id` greater than some given `_id` like this:

```
public List<SessionModel> GetSinceLast(string id) 
{
    ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(id);
    //var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt("_id", oid).ToBsonDocument();
    //var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt(x => x["_id"], oid).ToBsonDocument();
    var query = this.Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    return query.Result;
}
```

I am getting 0 results back from the GetSinceLast method. I have also tried switching the Gt to Lt but still 0 so I suspect there is something wrong with the filter/query.

I'm using `mongocsharpdriver 2.4.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Find](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find.htm) method takes the filter definition or expression. So update your filters to

```
// Filter Definition
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt("_id", oid);
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt(x => x["_id"], oid);
```

More examples here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/getting_started/quick_tour/#query-the-collection

Comment: Thank you. It lead me on the right track. Your suggestion generated another compile error: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Session.SessionModel, bool>>'`. By replacing `BsonDocument` in the Builder<T> with `SessionModel` I got everything to work as expected. So my end flter definition became: `var filter = Builders<SessionModel>.Filter.Gt("_id", oid);`